# how to restrict docker to pull/push to specific registry

Tags: docker

Is there a way to pull docker images from your own registry without providing the registry name

something like 
`docker pull alpine`  should pull my image from `docker pull docker-myorganisation.com/alpine`

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible, the reason is that it would break the global namespace, which makes sense if you think about it, imagine the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM debian:latest

...
```

Would this refer to `debian:latest` on the official registry, or your own registry?

If you could willingly set your own default registry, the answer would be:

> It depends.

This would lead to all kinds of breakage when the author of the file assumes it will be official registry, but your settings say different.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not supported.

See also: [Github](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/7203)